# No history option under window tab in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm wanting to revert an Illustrator file that I last edited a while ago back to a previous iteration (if possible).

I am using Illustrator CS6, however I cannot seem to find `history` as an option when looking in the `window` tab

[image]

Is there a history to view in CS6 like there is in Photoshop CS6. Am I going mad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Illustrator CS6** has **no** History panel or feature.

You aren't missing it. It's not in the application anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Photoshop saves snapshots of your PSD file automatically as you make edits, so you can jump forth and back in the history panel. But those snapshots cannot be saved as you save your file. The history is lost irreversibly as soon as you close your file.

Legacy Illustrator doesn't have that history panel. It appeared in version 2022. But you can undo and redo steps as long as you don't close the file. You can set in the preferences how many undos are possible.

There exist vector drawing programs which save the whole history of the file so that you can close and reopen the file without losing any intermediate steps. They are known as parametric CAD programs. One can even change an intermediate step and then redo the rest of the steps automatically. If one really understands what he does he can make a properly modified design in this way. if he doesn't understand what he does the result can be an useless mess.

To prevent your harms to some degree in the future:

1. "Save as" with a new filename often. How often? So often that you can recall from your memory how to continue after opening the latest version which still has everything OK.
2. In case you one day have new Illustrator read carefully Adobe's guide https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/recovery-undo-automation.html